# Convert UTC time to specific time zone in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have to convert UTC time to some specific time zone, I have converted the sysdate to UTC,now I want to convert it to time zone specific, This is how I am converting sysdate to UTC

```
select cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as DATE) from dual;
```

I tried writing +5 before from keyword,but its returning the date after 5 days.

```
select cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as DATE)+5 from dual;
```

I have get the timezone offset with below query, but I have clue to use this in above query

```
SELECT TZ_OFFSET('US/Eastern') FROM DUAL;
```

How can I convert the UTC time to some timezone offset,something like below

```
select cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as DATE) from dual where TZ_OFFSET=+5;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the current UTC time using:

```
SELECT CAST( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE )
FROM   DUAL;
```

You can reverse the process to change a UTC `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` at `+04:00` using:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ( CAST( your_date AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE '+04:00'
FROM   your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, reverse query worked, I have done this
SELECT cast(FROM_TZ(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE'-4:00' as DATE)
FROM   dual

Comment: @Salman Why make it that complicated? `SELECT CAST( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL` would do the same thing!

Comment: I have to get only Date and Time not any other information thats why casting it, plz suggest any other option

Comment: @Salman The statement I gave you in the previous comment does exactly that without all the complication of changing the timestamp to the UTC time zone and then to date and then back to a timestamp without time zone and then to a time stamp at UTC and then to a different time zone and then back to a date.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to add on the time zone offset would give you problems with daylight savings adjustments.

You can use [the `at time zone` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions007.htm) to specify a conversion, but you don't need to convert to UTC first. If you do you might not get what you expect, without taking an extra step:

```
select systimestamp as sys_ts,
  sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as utc_ts,
  sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' as edt_ts
from dual;

SYS_TS                         UTC_TS                  EDT_TS                            
------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------------------
2017-10-05 11:30:41.023 +01:00 2017-10-05 10:30:41.023 2017-10-05 05:30:41.023 US/EASTERN
```

That says the time in New York is 05:30, when it's actually 06:30 at time of writing.

The `sys_extract_utc` function gives you the UTC equivalent of your system time, but with on embedded time zone info - it's a plain timestamp, not a timestamp with time zone. So when you adjust it, it's implicitly converted to the system time zone with no adjustment, leaving you with the wrong actual time.

You can specify that the extracted value is UTC using [the `from_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm):

```
select systimestamp as sys_ts,
  sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as utc_ts,
  from_tz(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'UTC') at time zone 'US/Eastern' as edt_ts
from dual;

SYS_TS                         UTC_TS                  EDT_TS                            
------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------------------
2017-10-05 11:30:41.144 +01:00 2017-10-05 10:30:41.144 2017-10-05 06:30:41.144 US/EASTERN
```

But you don't need to do that much work, you can just take the original time zone-aware `systimestamp` value and apply `at time zone` directly to that:

```
select systimestamp as sys_ts,
  systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern' as edt_ts
from dual;

SYS_TS                         EDT_TS                            
------------------------------ ----------------------------------
2017-10-05 11:30:41.271 +01:00 2017-10-05 06:30:41.271 US/EASTERN
```

Which you can then cast to a date data type if that is a requirement:

```
cast(from_tz(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'UTC') at time zone 'US/Eastern' as date)
```

or more simply:

```
cast(systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern' as date)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I just want date and time of specific time zone, I tried this query,but its giving me wrong time
 select  cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' as DATE) as edt_ts from dual;

Comment: @Salman - yes, I said in my answer that you'd get the wrong answer with that query. You've run the first query I showed, which I said wouldn't do what you expect. Did you try the second or third queries?